# Styling <input type="file">, cropped box-shadow and outline

Tags: css, input

I want my `<input type="file" />` button to look like all my other buttons.

Now, it's easy with all browsers thanks to :

- `::file-selector-button` (Firefox)
- `::-webkit-file-upload-button`
- `::-ms-browse`

This is what this input looks like in ShadowDOM :

```
<input type="file">
  <button tabindex="-1">
  <label>No file selected</label>
</input>
```

So, the button is within the input box so everything that's outsize this box is cropped (`box-shadow` and `outline`).

Do you have an idea to avoid this crop ?

I mean, I can add `padding` to the input but I have to calculate the `border-radius` spread, `outline` offset, correct `padding` with negative margins, etc.

I'm looking for something more flexible.

EDIT : `overflow:visible` on the input is not working. I don't know why

EDIT 2 : This is the default styling from resource://gre-ressource/forms.css (Firefox)

```
input[type=file] {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  overflow-clip-box: padding-box;
  color: unset;

  /* Revert rules which apply on all inputs. */
  appearance: none;
  -moz-default-appearance: none;
  cursor: default;

  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: unset;
}
```

This explains why `overflow:visible` doesn't work. Also, playing with `overflow-clip-box` doesn't changes anything. It is set in forms.css however specifications say this property is not implemented in Firefox. Plus, there is a [bug associated](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1661582)

EDIT 3 : Defining `overflow: visible !important` seems to override user agent styling, and it cancels `overflow-clip-box: padding-box;` as well but the overflowing content is still not visible.

Any workaround idea ?

```css
:root {
  --base-color: purple;
  --file-border: 2px solid var(--base-color);
  --file-border-radius: 5px;
  --file-background: gold;
  --file-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #888;
  --file-outline: 2px dadshed blue;
}

::file-selector-button {
  color: var(--base-color);
  border-radius: var(--file-border-radius);
  background-color: var(--file-background);
  border: var(--file-border);
  box-shadow: var(--file-box-shadow);
}
::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  color: var(--base-color);
  border-radius: var(--file-border-radius);
  background-color: var(--file-background);
  border: var(--file-border);
  box-shadow: var(--file-box-shadow);
}
::-ms-browse {
  color: var(--base-color);
  border-radius: var(--file-border-radius);
  background-color: var(--file-background);
  border: var(--file-border);
  box-shadow: var(--file-box-shadow);
}

[type=file]:focus::file-selector-button{
  outline: var(--file-outline);
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
[type=file]:focus::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  outline: var(--file-outline);
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
[type=file]:focus::-ms-browse {
  outline: var(--file-outline);
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

```html
Cropped box-shadow and outline (on focus) :
<p>
  <input type="file" />
</p>
With padding :
<p>
  <input type="file" style="padding: 5px"/>
</p>
With padding + correction :
<p>
  <input type="file" style="padding: 5px;margin-left:-5px;margin-top:-5px"/>
</p>
```

Comment: Please no solutions about hiding the original button and style with label ;)

Comment: Why not? That's the usual solution for when you want to style a file input.

Comment: Because browsers now allow to style the button totally. So I think that's a bummer not to use the proper selectors. However the spec didn't go through with its idea when it forgot to take overflow in account. Plus I'm looking for a full CSS solution because I'm working on a theming tool. I don't want to use a wrapper or JavaScript to display the selected file name.

Comment: Pseudo elements also get clipped. One not so cool workaround could be, as it's an inline-block element, to use `line-height: 29px;`.

Comment: Hope it's gonna work on Firefox as it blocks the line-height value on inputs. Thanks though, gonna try that

Comment: Well, nothing interesting to do with line-height.

Comment: You can simplify `padding: 5px;margin-left:-5px;margin-top:-5px` with just `padding-bottom: 5px;`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in Chrome and Firefox.

That's because user agent stylesheets from the rendering engines of these browsers ([Blink](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css;drc=708a1a924f602233135685cd3e73a34f4f1509f6;l=606) and [Gecko](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/layout/style/res/forms.css#L672)) declare `overflow: hidden !important;` inside the selector `input[type=file]`. Unfortunately, [they can't be overrided](https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/you-cant-override-important-user-agent-css-declarations/) due to [CSS cascading order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#cascading_order).

The `!important` rule in UA stylesheets will bypass even a JS solution (I tried).

Answer (score 0):

> I mean, I can add padding to the input but I have to calculate the border-radius spread, outline offset, correct padding with negative margins, etc.

You don't have to do the calculations, just use `padding-bottom` directly instead of setting `padding` on all sides.

Edit: You can also make another custom variable to control the `padding` in one place. Since you have no issue setting the shadow as custom property as well. See the snippet below:

```css
:root {
  --base-color: purple;
  --file-border: 2px solid var(--base-color);
  --file-border-radius: 5px;
  --file-background: gold;
  --file-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #888;
  --file-outline: 2px dashed blue;
  --file-padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

::file-selector-button {
  color: var(--base-color);
  border-radius: var(--file-border-radius);
  background-color: var(--file-background);
  border: var(--file-border);
  box-shadow: var(--file-box-shadow);
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  color: var(--base-color);
  border-radius: var(--file-border-radius);
  background-color: var(--file-background);
  border: var(--file-border);
  box-shadow: var(--file-box-shadow);
}

::-ms-browse {
  color: var(--base-color);
  border-radius: var(--file-border-radius);
  background-color: var(--file-background);
  border: var(--file-border);
  box-shadow: var(--file-box-shadow);
}

[type=file]:focus::file-selector-button {
  outline: var(--file-outline);
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

[type=file]:focus::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  outline: var(--file-outline);
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

[type=file]:focus::-ms-browse {
  outline: var(--file-outline);
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

input{
  padding: var(--file-padding);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="file" />
</p>
```

Comment: It's not flexible. What if people want a top-left shadow? How do I know how much padding I have to set depending on box-shadow spread ? Thanks for your answer anyway :)